# Listing the object inside the listed array of json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I'm trying to list my JSON array from a file using jquery $.getJSON

Here is what I have for now:

```
(document).ready(function() {
    var theAPI = "test.js";

    $("button").click(function() {
        $.getJSON(theAPI, function(result) {
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                $("div").append(i + " - - - " + field + "<br/>");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and my output is:

kind - - - mykind

nextPageToken - - - CAUQAA

pageInfo - - - [object Object]

How do I append this [object Object]?
here is the test.js:

```
{
 "kind": "mykind",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",

 "pageInfo": {

  "totalResults": 1691,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 }

}
```

**UPDATE**
JSON.stringify() is not an answer, I want to list every json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a generic solution to this would be great because sometime in the future your JSON structure might change and become more complex.

Hence, I have attempted to come up with a generic solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kapz927/dzvLoo39/)

```
var result = {
    "key-1": "value-1",
    "key-2": "value-2",
    "key-3": {
        "key-31": "value-31",
        "key-32": "value-32",
        "key-33": ["value-331", "value-332", "value-333"],
        "key-34": {
            "key-341": 341,
            "key-342": 342,
            "key-343": [3431],
            "key-344": true,
            "key-345": false,
            "key-346": {
                "key-3461": [3461, "value-3462", true, false]
            }
        }
    },
    "key-4": "value-4",
    "key-5": ["value-51", "value-52"],
    "key-6": {
        "key-61": "value-61",
        "key-62": ["value-621", "value-622"],
        "key-63": {
            "key-631": "value-631",
            "key-632": true,
            "key-633": false
        }
    },
    "key-7": function() {
        console.log("I am a function...");
    }
};

var tabCount = 0,
    typeMap = {
        "STRING": "[object String]",
        "NUMBER": "[object Number]",
        "BOOLEAN": "[object Boolean]",
        "ARRAY": "[object Array]",
        "OBJECT": "[object Object]",
        "FUNCTION": "[object Function]"
    },
    getTypeOfObject = function(o) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(o);
    },
    getTabSpacing = function(numberOfTabs) {
        var tab = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;",
            result = "";
        for(var index = 0; index < numberOfTabs; index++) {
            result += tab;
        }
        return result;
    },
    iterator = function(obj, tab) {
        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
            if(getTypeOfObject(value) === typeMap.OBJECT) {
                $("div").append(getTabSpacing(tab) + key + ":<br/>");
                iterator(value, ++tabCount);
                --tabCount;
            }
            else {
                $("div").append(getTabSpacing(tab) + key + ": " + value + "<br/>");
            }
        });    
    };

iterator(result, tabCount);
```

I am not sure if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Elegant but in my opinion way over the top given the JSON in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one level of nesting you can do

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.getJSON(theAPI, function(result){
    $.each(result, function(key, value){
      if (key=="pageInfo") { // or typeof value=="object"
        $.each(value, function(pKey, pValue){  
          $("div").append(pKey+ " - - - " +pValue + "<br/>");
        });
      }
      else {
          $("div").append(key+ " - - - " +value + "<br/>");
      }
    });

  });
});
```

otherwise you will need to recourse

Example:

```js
var result = {

  "kind": "mykind",

  "lineInfo": {
    "totalLineResults": 691,
    "resultsPerLine": 9
  },

  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",

  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1691,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  }
}

$.each(result, function(key, value) {
  if (typeof value=="object") {
    $("div").append(key + "<ul>");
    $.each(value, function(pKey, pValue) {
      $("div").append("<li>"+pKey + " - - - " + pValue + "</li>");
    });
    $("div").append("</ul>");
  } else {
    $("div").append(key + " - - - " + value + "<br/>");
  }
});
```

```css
ul { display:inline }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: this is understandable but you have a lot of typeerrors :/

Comment: Which do you mean? I just updated my code

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME! thanks man :) i totally forgot about the loop inside the loop :)

Comment: What if I have more than one object? is there a way to list all objects like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify it like this (here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w445o6sz/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var theAPI = "test.js";
$("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON(theAPI, function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            $("div").append(i+ " - - - " +JSON.stringify(field)+ "<br/>");
        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked, but how can I access now just one property of it?
I just want to append total results

Comment: I cannot understand your question.

Comment: I don't want these "" around the data inside test.js. 

is there something like append(i, field.pageinfo);

Answer (score 0):

User JSON.stringify()

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON(theAPI, function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            $("div").append(i+ " - - - " +JSON.stringify(field) + "<br/>");
        });
    });
});
```